# how to test that fetch response is a type of ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch, arraybuffer

I have a function that returns arrayBuffer type response, this function is fetching the .jpeg or .pdf data and then I use it to show document in the browser:

```js
export async function getStatementsPDF(url: string, statement: Statement, setError: (err: any) => void) {
  return await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      reportNumber: statement.reportNumber,
      creationDate: statement.creationDate,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.arrayBuffer();
      }
      throw new Error('Something goes wrong while fetching your statement!');
    })
    .catch((err) => setError(err));
}
```

now I try to test this function with jest and [msw](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/binary-response-type)
I have mocked my response and now in the console I see that my function returns
ArrayBuffer

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { getJointAccountsStatementsPDF } from '../index';
import { rest } from 'msw';

const URL = 'http://localhost:1234/testing';
const server = setupServer(
  rest.post(URL, (_, res, ctx) => {
    // Read the image from the file system using the "fs" module.
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './statement-demo.pdf'));
    return res(
      ctx.set('Content-Length', imageBuffer.byteLength.toString()),
      ctx.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'),
      // Respond with the "ArrayBuffer".
      ctx.body(imageBuffer),
    );
  }),
);

describe('getStatementsPDF', () => {
  test.only('should return ArrayBuffer', async () => {
    server.listen();
    const res = await getStatementsPDF(
      URL,
      { creationDate: '2022-11-11', reportNumber: '21313', title: 'title' },
      (err) => {},
    );
    console.log('res', res);
    expect(res instanceof ArrayBuffer).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

But this:

```
expect(res instanceof ArrayBuffer).toEqual(true);
```

did not return true.

How can I make sure that my response type is ArrayBuffer?

Comment: You haven't shown `getJointAccountsStatementsPDF`, which is what creates `res`. We can't help you with code we can't see. Did you mean to use `getStatementsPDF`?

Comment: Re `getStatementsPDF`: You might as well remove the `async` and `await` if you're going to use explicit promise callbacks anyway. Or better yet, don't use explicit promise callbacks and just use `await`.

Comment: Sorry, you right getJointAccountsStatementsPDF is actualy getStatementsPDF. I have already edited this.

Answer (score 3):

The promise that your `getStatementsPDF` function returns doesn't always get fulfilled with an `ArrayBuffer`. Sometimes, it gets fulfilled with `undefined` (assuming `setError` doesn't have an explicit `return` with a value). The reason is this:

```
.catch((err) => setError(err));
```

That converts rejection into fulfillment with the return value of `setError`.

One of the most common mistakes with promises is handling rejection too early. `getStatementsPDF` should almost certainly **not** handle rejection, so that the rejection gets propagated to the caller, which can see that the operation failed and act accordingly.

But if you're going to have `getStatementsPDF` do that, then you should be prepared for `await getStatementsPDF` to sometimes result in `undefined`.

Here's a version of the function that A) Doesn't handle errors prematurely, and B) Uses `await` rather than explicit promise callback functions:

```
export async function getStatementsPDF(url: string, statement: Statement) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            reportNumber: statement.reportNumber,
            creationDate: statement.creationDate,
        }),
    });
    if (response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something goes wrong while fetching your statement!');
    }
    return await response.arrayBuffer();
    //     ^^^^^−−−−− this isn't strictly necessary, but it can make the `async`
    //                call stack clearer about where the error occurred
}
```

The caller would handle rejection when calling it. Your test probably doesn't need to, because I assume the test should fail if the function rejects its promise.

Comment: thank you for this comment, I will do so with error handling!

My issue is when even my promise is fulfilled with ArrayBuffer
and I see in the  console.log my response, I do not now how to test the expect :
       ArrayBuffer {
        [Uint8Contents]: <25 25 45 20 4d 45 44 49 41 3a 20 50 4b 50 4d 2e 43 48 44 37 32 36 4b 2e 50 44 46 4f 55 54 30 31 2e 5a 31 31 37 35 44 45 4a 2e 50 41 ... 115691 more bytes>,
        byteLength: 115791

Comment: @Detoner - The code in the question, if it doesn't fulfill the promise with `undefined`, will definitely fulfill it with an `ArrayBuffer` unless that `fetch` is not the standard one.